Connected App Status Using SOQL
Can i get the status whether the connected app is blocked/unblocked or installed/uninstalled using SOQL?.
I did extensive surfing across salesforce's documentation but couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

see OAuthToken. See also  this q&a

Unfortunately, Salesforce doesn't provide a direct "Blocked" field for connected apps via the API as far as I can tell.
You can use these SOQLs, which might help though...
ConnectedApp:
SELECT id , Name, SystemModstamp, OptionsAllowAdminApprovedUsersOnly from ConnectedApplication WHERE Name = 'Workbench'

And then querying the OauthToken as cropredy mentioned would be a good next step. (If it finds 0 records, that means it is either been blocked OR nobody has yet logged in and generated an oAuthToken yet.) However if it DOES find a record, it is definitely unblocked from the UI in your screenshot.
OauthToken:
SELECT id , AccessToken, UserId, UseCount from OauthToken WHERE AppName = 'Workbench'

